# running a Python script from a Node.Js application

Tags: python, node.js

I absolutely love using Node.JS for my web projects but i also love using Python at the same time, so i have been wondering, if is it possible to run Python scripts from Node, for example my Node.JS backend calls a python script to retrive some data from a SQL Database and gives it back to Node (i know i can do that all in Node but just using an example). 
 
I thought about doing it this way 
 
1.Node creates a Json files which contains the variable the Python script will use(for example name:Jon birthDate:1996) 
2.It runs a python script that reads those variables from that Json file(so it searches for Jon born in 1996) 
3.It deletes the Json file when its done 
4.Rinse and Repeat

Would this be a good and safe way of doing this type of thing or are there any other ways of running and "modifiying" the Python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build a node app, but for the backend calculations, it seemed better to use NumPy and Pandas, so I did what you are doing... in the end I found an npm package called [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell).

It works via promises, so I'd call my calculation script, and also would do some clean up with another Python script if there were any errors.

Worked pretty good. Code was something like this:

```
const PythonShell = require('python-shell');

router.get('/calc', (req, res) => {
    PythonShell.run('py/calculate.py', {pyPath: pyPath , args: [tmpPath],}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            PythonShell.run('py/clean_up.py', {pyPath: pyPath, args: [tmpPath2]}, function(err, results2) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.json(
                    {
                        message: "error: Running clean up",
                        ang: 0,
                        vec: 0,
                    }
                );
            });
        } else {
            let data = JSON.parse(results);
            let message = data[0];
            let ang = data[1];
            let vec = data[2];
            res.json(
                {
                    message: message,
                    ang: ang,
                    vec: vec,
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```